# Turn long line code into multilines (SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character)

Tags: python, python-3.x

python3.5

regular expression

```
Monat_pattern = r"(?P<Monat>[A-Z][a-z][a-z])"
Tag_pattern = r"(?P<Tag>\d\d)"
Uhrzeit_pattern = r"(?P<Uhrzeit>\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)"
Servername_pattern = r"(?P<Servername>[\w|\.]*)"
ServerID_pattern = r"(?P<ServerID>\w*\[\d*\]:\s\w*)"
```

concate them:

```
pattern = Monat_pattern + r"\s*" +\\
          Tag_pattern + r"\s*" +\\
          Uhrzeit_pattern + r"\s*" +\\
          Servername_pattern + r"\s*"+\\ 
          ServerID_pattern + r"\s*
```

learned if there is "\" in the string, I need to use "\\" for the concatenation

I get error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-115-1ca2b20ef199>", line 1
    pattern = Monat_pattern + r"\s*" +\          Tag_pattern + r"\s*" +\          Uhrzeit_pattern + r"\s*" +\          Servername_pattern + r"\s*"+\\
                                                                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: Why are you using *double* backslashes? You only need one.

Comment: You don't need to escape backslashes outside of string literals.

Comment: you might want to try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8 to automatically format code

Comment: @titus: autopep8 makes too many mistakes for my taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would only use *one* backslash:

```
pattern = Monat_pattern + r"\s*" +\
          Tag_pattern + r"\s*" +\
          Uhrzeit_pattern + r"\s*" +\
          Servername_pattern + r"\s*"+\
          ServerID_pattern + r"\s*"
```

Your actual code also included a space after one of the double backslashes, the backslash has to be the last character before the newline.

You'd be much better of using `(...)` parentheses to extend the logical line, however:

```
pattern = (
    Monat_pattern + r"\s*" +
    Tag_pattern + r"\s*" +
    Uhrzeit_pattern + r"\s*" +
    Servername_pattern + r"\s*"+
    ServerID_pattern + r"\s*")
```

You could perhaps use `str.join()` here:

```
pattern = r"\s*".join([
    Monat_pattern, Tag_pattern, Uhrzeit_pattern,
    Servername_pattern, ServerID_pattern, ''])
```

The trailing `''` makes sure an extra `\s*` is used after the `ServerID_pattern` string.

Comment: one backslash and (...) gives me Error "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"

Comment: @Hellolad: that's because your last string is missing the closing `"`. I was wondering wether or not to point that out or if it was simply a typo in your question.